# Verify button padding from browser border

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a small web login form with buttons and logo.

Is it possible to get the padding space of the buttons and logo. I would like to verify that button is not close to the web browser frame than 10 pixes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `element.getLocation()`.

```
package selenium;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Penzov extends WebDriverSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
        WebElement logo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://stackoverflow.com']"));
        int logoX = logo.getLocation().getX();
        int logoY = logo.getLocation().getY();
        int logoWidth = logo.getRect().getWidth();
        int logoHeight = logo.getRect().getHeight();
        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int screenWidth = (int) dimension.getWidth();
        int screenHeight = (int) dimension.getHeight();
        System.out.println("Logo is " + logoX + " pixels from left border.");
        System.out.println("Logo is " + (screenWidth - logoX + logoWidth) + " pixels from right border.");
        System.out.println("Logo is " + logoY + " pixels from top border.");
        System.out.println("Logo is " + (screenHeight - logoY + logoHeight) + " pixels from bottom border.");
        driver.quit();
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 86.0.4240.22 (398b0743353ff36fb1b82468f63a3a93b4e2e89e-refs/branch-heads/4240@{#378}) on port 12429
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Pro 03, 2020 9:57:25 DOP. org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Logo is 363 pixels from left border.
Logo is 1723 pixels from right border.
Logo is 3 pixels from top border.
Logo is 1124 pixels from bottom border.
```